# What else did Robert C O'brien write?

Tags: books, robert-c-obrien

When I was thirteen, [Z for Zachariah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_For_Zachariah) is the book that got me hooked on science fiction. Was wondering if anyone knows of any other literature that he wrote? Wikipedia says that he is "best known for writing children's books under the O'Brien pen name" and lists four novels under a 'selected bibliography'

- The Silver Crown (1968)
- Mrs. Frisby and the Rats of NIMH (1971)
- A Report from Group 17 (1972)
- Z for Zachariah (1975)

Comment: Regarding quick close, 'selected bibliography' means that it is not exhaustive. Precisely the reason I was asking if anyone knew of anything else. Quick trigger fingers are a surefire way to ditch people interested in participating in the community :(

Comment: Voting to reopen because (a) "general reference" hasn't been a valid close reason for years, and (b) Wikipedia says the author is dead, so barring Tolkien-levels of unpublished manuscripts, the answer to this question is going to be a fixed list, and thus the question is not too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the internet book list, that's the lot - http://www.iblist.com/author2290.htm

Comment: Thanks! I've never seen this site before! I will +1 your answer as soon as I have some more votes :)